# OpenCV VideoCapture with HTTPS

Tags: java, opencv, ssl, video-streaming

I'm streaming an MJPEG over the network to a Java OpenCV client program.  It reads the stream like this:

```
VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture();
capture.open("http://10.0.0.5:8080/DerpStreamer/StreamingServlet?dummy=video.mjpg");
// loop for reading jpg frames
```

This works fine and dandy.  I'm wanting to experiment sending this mjpeg over SSL just for fun.  I know it would be much slower, maybe there's a better way to encrypt videos for streaming?  Anyway, I installed SSL on my web server, verified it was working and then blindly just changed the URL string to https://x.x.x.x:8443

It didn't work, and I realized it was because my client wasn't decrypting with the public key.  My client knows nothing about SSL right now.  So I did some digging and found some examples of how to write a simple Java SSL client.  But when I looked at the VideoCapture API I didn't see a way to make it work.  It won't take any kind of Reader or InputStream, only a device ID or Filename.  I guess I could decrypt it, write it to some file or pipe, and then have VideoCapture read that, but it would make it even slower.  Is that a reasonable thing to do, or is it incredibly stupid and I should forget about sending the video over SSL?

Any suggestions?

How much of a slow down should I anticipate if I switch from HTTP to HTTPS for my video streaming?

Comment: When I look at the docs for VideoCapture there isn't an overloaded method that takes a string like you show... which version are you using? http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/highgui/VideoCapture.html

Comment: 2.4.9.  Here's the description of param in my IDE:  Parameters:
filename name of the opened video file (eg. video.avi) or image sequence (eg. img_%02d.jpg, which will read samples like img_00.jpg, img_01.jpg, img_02.jpg,...).  It works with a URL String as well.  I'm guessing it just tries to open whatever you give it as an InputStream.

Comment: We need to know what it is you have exactly in order for us to figure a "hack". Can you provide online docs for the methods/class that shows this?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html

Comment: What is your import statement for the class?

Comment: import org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58916/discussion-between-xabster-and-medloh).

Comment: imho, it's the videocapture, not your class, that has to do ssl

Comment: Actually it's both.  My webserver sending the mjpeg stream has to encrypt it with it's SSL private key.  That part is taken care of and working.  Then whatever client is consuming it will need to have the public key to decrypt it before my OpenCV stuff can chop out and process the images.